# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}4\sin(n!)\left(\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}\right)^{10}$

Tags: limits

What is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}4\sin(n!)\left(\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}\right)^{10}$$

By my reasoning, we can use limit arithmetic here.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_nb_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n)
$$
$n$ approaches infinity in all limits.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}\right)^{10} = 0
$$ 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(n!)$ - doesn't exist because $\sin$ is a periodic function.

There are two options then:
1) $0$ times whatever $\sin(n!)$ currently is, is still $0$ therefore, $\lim(a_nb_n)=0$
2) the limit doesn't exist.

Which is correct?

Comment: $|\sin(\theta)|\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n$ is a bounded sequence and $b_n$ converges to zero, then so does $a_nb_n$. So 1) is correct.

Edit: You cannot write $\lim a_nb_n = \lim a_n \lim b_n$ if $a_n$ doesn't converge.

Answer (score 0):

For any small $\epsilon$, you know that for large enough $n$ you will have $$\left\lvert\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}\right\rvert<\epsilon$$ But that means for large enough $n$: $$\left\lvert\sin(n!)\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}\right\rvert\leq\left\lvert\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}\right\rvert<\epsilon$$ because $\left\lvert\sin(n!)\right\rvert\leq1$. So $\left\lvert\sin(n!)\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}\right\rvert$ approahces $0$. By the Squeeze Theorem, since $$-\left\lvert\sin(n!)\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}\right\rvert\leq\sin(n!)\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}\leq\left\lvert\sin(n!)\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}\right\rvert$$ and the outer expressions approach $0$, so does $\sin(n!)\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}$.